# Windows Certificate Authority - Adding Additional Attributes

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, attributes

In **AD Certificate Templates** the templates have an option to **build from AD information** and includes Email, DNS, UPN, etc.

[image]

When creating a CSR using powershell, openssl and the certificate mmc snap-in I know its possible to add additional attributes like State, City, Organization, Organization Unit, Locality and others. Is it possible to **have this type of information pulled from AD** so when servers are set to **auto-enroll** this kind of additional information is included in the cert?

I know additional information can be added to AD users/objects using **Attribute Editor** but I'm not sure if you can specify **certificate templates to pull this information**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not with built-in functionality. You have to write a custom policy module by implementing [ICertPolicy2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certpol/nn-certpol-icertpolicy2) interface and then inside [ICertPolicy::VerifyRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certpol/nf-certpol-icertpolicy-verifyrequest) call [ICertServerPolicy::SetCertificateProperty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/certif/nf-certif-icertserverpolicy-setcertificateproperty) to modify subject to include custom RDNs.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a policy module in C#, find it here: https://github.com/Sleepw4lker/TameMyCerts.

The upcoming version will definitely include the feature you described for user accounts. Maybe I'll implement it for machine accounts as well.

Kind regards